# Dynamic Memory issue in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

so I was writing a program which has to check if the input sting is a palindrome or not. And it's actually working but a problem with deleting the array I created during the course of it arouse.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool checkPalindrome(char* text);
char* clearString(char* src);


int main() 
{
    char buffer[1000];
    cin.getline(buffer, 1000);

    cout << boolalpha << checkPalindrome(buffer) << endl;

    return 0;
}


bool checkPalindrome(char* text)
{
    char* newStr = clearString(text);
    if (!newStr)
       return false;

    int newLen = strlen(newStr);

    for (int i = 0; i < newLen / 2; i++) {
        if (newStr[i] == newStr[newLen - i - 1])
            continue;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //delete[] newStr;

    return true;
}


char* clearString(char* src)
{
    unsigned len = strlen(src);
    unsigned counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (src[i] == ' '||src[i] == '.'||src[i] == ','||src[i] == '!')
            counter++;
    }

    unsigned newSize = len - counter + 1;
    char* dest = new(nothrow) char[newSize];

    if (!dest) {
        cout << "not enoough memory\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    int i, j;

    for(i = j = 0; j < newSize; ++i, ++j) {
        if(src[i]==' '||src[i]=='.'||src[i]==','||src[i]=='!'||src[i]=='?')
            i++;
        else
            dest[j] = src[i];
    }

    dest[j] = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

So the commentated delete in the checkPalindrome function causes a crash if executed and I get the "Heap corruption detected" error. I tried changing the function type to void and delete there and the same thing happened. Any ideas what causes it?

Comment: Please don't try using memory allocation yourself, that's just  error prone and chances are high you don't get it right. Just use appropriate standard c++ containers or `std::string`,

Comment: You allocate `newSize` chars and then write `newSize+1` chars.

Comment: It's not bad to manage your own memory *if you know what you're doing,* but it's often unnecessary, as it is in this case.

Comment: @Litty _"It's not bad to manage your own memory"_ I think we should consider it really is bad. In **most cases** it's not necessary. There's a few _advanced use cases_ that are far beyond what the OP's asking for.

Comment: I believe the "advanced" use cases are more than few, but point taken, it's irrelevant to the OP or the question.

Comment: It's also not bad to manage your own memory if you're trying to learn about memory management, which the OP might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop copies the `'\0'` at the end of the string, but then you add another `'\0'`, using one more byte of memory than you allocated.